# Saga call inside map not working

Tags: react-native, redux-saga, saga

Spent few hours trying to figure out how to run sagas inside a map in parallel.

Tried out what I found : `yield result.map(item => call(api.endpoint, item))`
But nothing seems to happen.

Here's what I was doing :

```
export function* syncCanvasesByFolder(<someParams>) {
    yield call(api.syncCanvasForFolder, <someParam>);
}

export default function* syncAllFoldersForSurvey(<someParams>) {

    // Get list of folder for a survey
    const folders = yield call(data.getFolderBySurvey, surveyId);

    //For each folder sync canvases

    yield all(folders.map(folder => {
           call(syncCanvasesByFolder, folder.id, lastSyncedAt, access_token)  
    }));

/*Sequential call*/
// for (const i in folders) {
//     if (folders.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
//         yield call(syncCanvasesByFolder, folders[i].id, lastSyncedAt, access_token);
//       //  yield call(canvasSyncSaga.syncAllCanvasesForFolder, folders[i].id, lastSyncedAt);
//     }
// }
}
```

Sequential call when done in a for loop is working. But nothing seems to happen inside the map. Not getting any `exception/errors` as well.

`syncCanvasesByFolder` never gets called when I am using map.

Comment: Resolved: Had to return inside map

   `yield all(folders.map(folder => {
           call(syncCanvasesByFolder, folder.id, lastSyncedAt, access_token)  
    }));`

Answer (score 4):

To implicitly return, don't use curly brackets `{}` inside function.

**With Brackets (Doesn't Work)**

```
yield all(folders.map(folder => {
    call(syncCanvasesByFolder, folder.id, lastSyncedAt, access_token)  
}));
```

**Without Brackets (Works)**

```
yield all(folders.map(folder => call(syncCanvasesByFolder, folder.id, lastSyncedAt, access_token)  
));
```

Answer (score 0):

With Brackets you have to use **return**

```
yield all(folders.map(folder => {
    return call(syncCanvasesByFolder, folder.id, lastSyncedAt, access_token)  
}));
```

Without Brackets return is implicit

```
yield all(folders.map(folder => call(syncCanvasesByFolder, folder.id, lastSyncedAt, access_token)  
));
```